# Why am I getting 500:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR on vercel when trying to deploy a django app?

Tags: python, django, deployment

Basically, I am trying to deploy a django project to vercel using the default settings, however I get this error when doing so

```
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: iad1::kgz72-1677350120288-41179987b8c3
```

The vercel website simply tells me to read the logs, The logs only provide the follwoing message

```
[GET] /favicon.ico
12:35:20:58
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[Heres the repository I am trying to deploy](https://github.com/AlcalinoGitHub/PPE.git)

Answer (score 0):

What exact steps are you doing?
From the error it looks like you simply did not install dependencies.
`pip install -r requirements.txt` (or pip3).

Comment: Where do I run this command? I'm guessing it's not in my IDE since it doesn't even work, does vercel have a console of some sort? Sorry, I'm really new to this

Comment: Apparently you need someone to help you with setup. Either look up Vercel documentation, ask support for assistance, or search for paid help.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to have `requirements.txt` in the root folder of your project, and Vercel will install those dependencies automatically.

Comment: @JDOaktown this is not a question. This is the answer to the OP's question.